# C# Socket Programming - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, sockets

I have written typical socket program in c#, where client requests something, server responds to it and both closes the connection.

Considering that there are no antivirus or firewall rule to block the connection. What may have caused this error **"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"**

I'm running an asynchronous programming paradigm for this. I'm getting this error only dozens of times for thousands of connection. I tried creating some scenario. I'm unable to reproduce the exception.

I feel this happens when the client disconnects without informing server.

It would really help if you can give proper reason when this happens exactly. This question is asked couple of times. but I didn't find satisfying the answer.

Since the asynchronous code is very big. I have written synchronous program and simulated. I got exception once and I missed it. Here is the code

**Server Code**

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(
    Dns.GetHostEntry(
        Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
        .Where(e => e.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        .First().ToString()
    );
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 5050));
serverSocket.Listen(10);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
int readCount = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
string readString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, readCount);
Debug.WriteLine(readString);
clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Response."));
clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
clientSocket.Close();
```

**Client Code**

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(e => e.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().ToString());
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, 5050));
clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi server"));
int receiveCount = clientSocket.Receive(buffer,0,5,SocketFlags.None);
Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveCount));
clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
clientSocket.Close();
```

Comment: Please post some example code - how are client / server handling closing the socket connection ?

Comment: Do you get that exception in same method each time? You need to show some code and where you get that exception. Otherwise it is really difficult to understand the issue.

Comment: As I said, Exception happens very rarely. It is difficult to reproduce. But I logged exceptions for the same. Let me add some code snippet.